# Birational geometry of Fano threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Smooth Fano threefolds, say over $\mathbb{C}$, have been completely classified, see for example *Algebraic Geometry V: Fano Varieties* by V.A. Iskovskih, Yu. G. Prokhorov.  The table in the appendix of this text gives a list of 17 families of prime Fano threefolds, namely those of Picard rank $\rho = 1$.  It is also more or less settled (at least for very general members of each family) which smooth Fano threefolds are rational.

My question is as follows:

> 1. Of the 17 families listed, 8 are rational, hence their members are all birational to one another.  Are there any non-rational smooth Fano threefolds with $\rho = 1$ from distinct families birational to one another?  If so, how can one see the transformations between them as a series of blow ups and blow downs?

Theorem 9.1.6 in the book above seems to list some cases where this can't occur due to birational rigidity, such as the case of the quartic threefold, but I couldn't locate a general statement.

Comment: The cubic threefold and the Fano threefold of degree 14 are birational. This is very classical, and can be found in many places — e.g. Theorem 4.6.6 in the book you mention.